# Dynamically changing (appending string to existing url) href using jquery is appending it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, attr

I am trying to dynamically append a string to href using jquery 'attr'. I am not able to understand why the below code that I wrote is appending the string twice in existing href. Please help. I have read a lot many articles but unfortunately not help.

```
var olduri = $('a.link').attr("href");
$('a.link').attr("href", olduri + 'www.google.com');
```

HTML code is:

```
<div>
     <a class="link" target="_blank" title="Welcome" href="https://example.com?redirect=www.test.com&amp;">
            Click</a>
</div>
```

Result is:
**https://example.com?redirect=www.test.com&www.google.comwww.google.com**

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is coming twice. Please help me get it fixed.

Comment: i tested above code ..didn't find any such behaviour .Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/b1sn5omd/) . It would be good if you could include demo code to understand actual problem .

Comment: are you clicking twice

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want the `&amp;` as the only separator for these but my suggestion for a cleaner approach is to update the `search` property not the attribute

```js
$('a.link').prop("search", function(i, curr){
    return curr + 'www.google.com';
});
console.log($('a.link')[0].href)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="link" target="_blank" title="Welcome" href="https://example.com?redirect=www.test.com&amp;">
            Click</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works fine. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yopez83/d2u9ack1/1/). Also a bit of context would really help. Are you planning to append the url onclick event?

```
$('.showUri').text($('a.link').attr("href"));

$('a.link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
  var oldUri = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', oldUri + 'www.google.com');
  
  $('.showUri').text($('a.link').attr("href"));
});

<div>
     <a class="link" target="_blank" title="Welcome" href="https://example.com?redirect=www.test.com&amp;">
            Click</a>
</div>

<p class="showUri"></p>
```

Comment: yes, my target is to append the given string to url when user clicks on the link.

Comment: @Kiran I just updated the code. Take a look at the link as well so you can run it